# Analyze cpu usage when do stress on cpu

Tags: stress-testing

How can I analyze my cpu when I run stress on cpu?
When I enter the following command for any value of n: (For example 5, 10, 20, 40)

```
sudo stress --cpu n --timeout 40s
```

The `top` command result for cpu usage is 100%. So when I change the n value, what will be change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"n" should be the number of cores (threads) you want to stress. If you have 4 core CPU without hyperthreading a value of 2 should give you about 50% load etc.

Comment: Oh, ‍‍the N in`spawn N workers spinning on sqrt()`that is written in stress document, means N cpu cores?

Comment: N is how many threads the stress will run so you can think of it as how many cores will be stressed, sure.